# Magento - How to use product link widget to display "name - price" on homepage

Tags: php, magento

I currently have a static block loaded into my homepage which then loads several product link widgets.

The idea is to created a list of 3 products

name - price
name - price
name - price

so i've tried to edit template\catalog\product\widget\link\link_inline.phtml to include the price information using

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();

echo $_product->getFinalPrice();
```

but this causes a blank white screen.

Using

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16)
```

works to retrieve the price info but ideally i dont want to hard code the product ID's i want them to be picked up using the widget select product dialogue

So i think i need something along the lines of:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct());
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by looping through $this to retrieve a string that is passed "product/id"

I then remove the "product/" using regex which leaves just the product ID and can then use

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ID);
```

and then in turn

```
$price = $_product->getPrice();
```

to get the price.

This works for the question i asked but i'm sure there must be a better way? But as no-one else answered this is how i achieved it.